# Is a text file still open after a open(file).read() command?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pycharm

To shorten the code a little, I used something like:

```
data = open(file).read()
```

It's impossible to close by `data.close()` since `data` it's a string, so I ask the question: if after that line is read, is the file still open? Do I need to bother to close it somehow?

Answer (score 3):

It will (probably, see comments) be closed when garbage collected; however the cleanest way to handle it is within a `with` block:

```
with open(file, "r") as datafile:
    data = datafile.read()
```

If the process is short-lived, it shouldn't cause too much trouble, but it's good practice to release the handle as soon as it becomes unnecessary.

Comment: "Unless you close the file, yes, it will remain open." This isn't true: in CPython, the temporary file object will be garbage collected immediately and closed. In other Python variants (IronPython, Jython), the file object will be closed next time garbage collection runs.

Comment: Is that per the standard or is it implementation dependent?

Comment: Yeah, it's not part of the language reference itself; the behaviour is definitely implementation dependent. What's interesting is that I can't even find a mention in the documentation about the file automatically being closed when the corresponding file object garbage is collected: you'd think that would be explicit somewhere. (Maybe I'm just missing it.)

Comment: Alright, then I guess the technically correct answer is "it might be collected"; you shouldn't really rely on it.

Comment: Yes, maybe. It'll *definitely* be collected immediately in all current versions of CPython. It seems pretty unlikely that that would change in a future version of CPython, but who knows...  In any case, ignoring technical correctness, I absolutely agree with your current answer: the real answer is simply "don't do that; use a `with` statement (or some equivalent construct) instead".

Answer (score 3):

In CPython the result of `open(file)` will have no references to it after `.read()` completes if there were no exceptions, so it will be instantly garbage collected which will cause it to close.

But don't do this. Make a convenience function:

```
def read_file(path):
    with open(path) as f:
        return f.read()

data = read_file(path)
```

Also don't fuss about saving a line of code. That attitude will lead to bad code.

Answer (score 0):

yes, it will remain open ,my way to open data like this:

```
with open("file","rb") as f：
       data=f.readlines()
```

or

```
datas=open("file","rb")
data=datas.readlines()
```

wish i could help you